# Fullscreen Citrix applications causing mouse offset

Tags: linux, gnome, citrix, citrix-receiver

I am using Fedora 23 with Gnome and the latest Citrix Receiver. I need to use Citrix to open Windows applications for work and I am having an issue where when I try to maximize or full screen any application, the Gnome top bar seems to get in the way which causes me to have an offset cursor. I need to click a full cursor-length below the object I want to click on for a click to register.

My "solution" so far has been to run Remote Desktop Connection in 1440x900, but I'd rather take advantage of a full 1920x1080 work space.

Does anyone know of a way to make Citrix applications override the Gnome top bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user "uncon" on the #Citrix IRC channel on FreeNode gave me a solution that does exactly what I want: Use the Citrix Receiver Chrome Extension. It lets me log in to my company's storefront and loads ICA files directly, creating my "full screen" 1920x1056 window with no mouse offset. PERFECT!

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/citrix-receiver/haiffjcadagjlijoggckpgfnoeiflnem/